# NDK Issue: crash on 32bit, inconsistency on 64bit

Tags: c++, android-ndk, cmake, clang++, android-ndk-r4

I have this problem with my c++ code. It's a doing a graph search and it uses multiple threads. The threads don't depend on each other, they each have different search parameters, but will access read only the source graph, write only the results array and read and write the job queue.

On **32bit** devices: arm or x86 it will crash randomly on a new call. Be it a `struct`, `class`, `std::vector<>` or when a `std::vector<>` will have to reallocate memory to allow for a larger capacity.

Here's a sample:

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:6.0.1/M4B30Z/3437181:user/release-keys'
pid: 2341, tid: 2356, name: roidJUnitRunner  >>> com.transit102.nativesearchengine.test <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xdeadcab1
Stack frame 03-19 20:44:41.379  2142  2142 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00016fce  /data/app/com.transit102.nativesearchengine.test-1/lib/arm/libtransit-searchengine.so: Routine __gabixx::__default_terminate() at /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r14-release/out/build/tmp/build-22588/build-stlport/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gabi++/src/terminate.cc:72
Stack frame 03-19 20:44:41.379  2142  2142 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 00016fe3  /data/app/com.transit102.nativesearchengine.test-1/lib/arm/libtransit-searchengine.so: Routine __gabixx::__terminate(void (*)()) at /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r14-release/out/build/tmp/build-22588/build-stlport/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gabi++/src/terminate.cc:84
Stack frame 03-19 20:44:41.379  2142  2142 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 00016fb9  /data/app/com.transit102.nativesearchengine.test-1/lib/arm/libtransit-searchengine.so: Routine std::terminate() at /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r14-release/out/build/tmp/build-22588/build-stlport/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gabi++/src/terminate.cc:110 (discriminator 1)
Stack frame 03-19 20:44:41.379  2142  2142 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 00016745  /data/app/com.transit102.nativesearchengine.test-1/lib/arm/libtransit-searchengine.so: Routine __cxxabiv1::call_terminate(_Unwind_Control_Block*) at /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r14-release/out/build/tmp/build-22588/build-stlport/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gabi++/src/helper_func_internal.cc:54
Stack frame 03-19 20:44:41.379  2142  2142 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 000162dd  /data/app/com.transit102.nativesearchengine.test-1/lib/arm/libtransit-searchengine.so: Routine (anonymous namespace)::throwException(__cxxabiv1::__cxa_exception*) at /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r14-release/out/build/tmp/build-22588/build-stlport/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gabi++/src/cxxabi.cc:271
Stack frame 03-19 20:44:41.379  2142  2142 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 000162a3  /data/app/com.transit102.nativesearchengine.test-1/lib/arm/libtransit-searchengine.so: Routine __cxa_throw at /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r14-release/out/build/tmp/build-22588/build-stlport/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gabi++/src/cxxabi.cc:335
Stack frame 03-19 20:44:41.379  2142  2142 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 00016cab  /data/app/com.transit102.nativesearchengine.test-1/lib/arm/libtransit-searchengine.so (_Znwj+70): Routine operator new(unsigned int) at /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r14-release/out/build/tmp/build-22588/build-stlport/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gabi++/src/new.cc:105
Stack frame 03-19 20:44:41.379  2142  2142 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 0000e0a5  /data/app/com.transit102.nativesearchengine.test-1/lib/arm/libtransit-searchengine.so (_ZSt9__stl_newj+12): Routine std::__stl_new(unsigned int) at C:/Users/auras/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport\stl/_new.h:134
Stack frame 03-19 20:44:41.379  2142  2142 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 0000e081  /data/app/com.transit102.nativesearchengine.test-1/lib/arm/libtransit-searchengine.so (_ZNSt12__node_alloc8allocateERj+24): Routine std::__node_alloc::allocate(unsigned int&) at C:/Users/auras/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport\stl/_alloc.h:158 (discriminator 1)
Stack frame 03-19 20:44:41.379  2142  2142 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 0000e6f3  /data/app/com.transit102.nativesearchengine.test-1/lib/arm/libtransit-searchengine.so (_ZNSaIjE11_M_allocateEjRj+102): Routine std::allocator<unsigned int>::_M_allocate(unsigned int, unsigned int&) at C:/Users/auras/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport\stl/_alloc.h:348
Stack frame 03-19 20:44:41.379  2142  2142 F DEBUG   :     #10 pc 0000e685  /data/app/com.transit102.nativesearchengine.test-1/lib/arm/libtransit-searchengine.so (_ZNSt4priv17_STLP_alloc_proxyIPjjSaIjEE8allocateEjRjRKSt11__true_type+40): Routine std::priv::_STLP_alloc_proxy<unsigned int*, unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::allocate(unsigned int, unsigned int&, std::__true_type const&) at C:/Users/auras/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport\stl/_alloc.h:551
Stack frame 03-19 20:44:41.379  2142  2142 F DEBUG   :     #11 pc 0000e4f1  /data/app/com.transit102.nativesearchengine.test-1/lib/arm/libtransit-searchengine.so (_ZNSt4priv17_STLP_alloc_proxyIPjjSaIjEE8allocateEjRj+48): Routine std::priv::_STLP_alloc_proxy<unsigned int*, unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::allocate(unsigned int, unsigned int&) at C:/Users/auras/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport\stl/_alloc.h:531
Stack frame 03-19 20:44:41.379  2142  2142 F DEBUG   :     #12 pc 00014c69  /data/app/com.transit102.nativesearchengine.test-1/lib/arm/libtransit-searchengine.so (_ZNSt4priv12_Vector_baseIjSaIjEEC2EjRKS1_+80): Routine _Vector_base at C:/Users/auras/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport\stl/_vector.h:71
Stack frame 03-19 20:44:41.379  2142  2142 F DEBUG   :     #13 pc 0001299f  /data/app/com.transit102.nativesearchengine.test-1/lib/arm/libtransit-searchengine.so (_ZNSt6vectorIjSaIjEEC2ERKS1_+66): Routine vector at C:/Users/auras/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport\stl/_vector.h:247
Stack frame 03-19 20:44:41.379  2142  2142 F DEBUG   :     #14 pc 0000ff61  /data/app/com.transit102.nativesearchengine.test-1/lib/arm/libtransit-searchengine.so (_ZN10transit10215NewSearchEngine7PushJobEjPSt6vectorIjSaIjEEjS4_jS4_hPS1_IPNS_7JourneyESaIS6_EE+240): Routine transit102::NewSearchEngine::PushJob(unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >*, unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >*, unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >*, unsigned char, std::vector<transit102::Journey*, std::allocator<transit102::Journey*> >*) at C:\Users\auras\AndroidStudioProjects\Transit102\nativesearchengine\src\main\jni/newsearchengine.cpp:965
```

The common denominator for crashes is always

```
Stack frame 03-19 20:44:41.379  2142  2142 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 00016cab  /data/app/com.transit102.nativesearchengine.test-1/lib/arm/libtransit-searchengine.so (_Znwj+70): Routine operator new(unsigned int) at /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r14-release/out/build/tmp/build-22588/build-stlport/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gabi++/src/new.cc:105
```

On **64bit** devices: arm or x64 it never crashes, even though I get different results every time I run the test which didn't happen before refactoring the code.

My main issue is the **crashing**, I can debug after that, if it still happens, why I get different results for every run.

**EDIT:**

I've ported the code to Visual Studio 2015 and the code never crashes on 32bit or 64bit and there are no memory leaks.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build your native library.
# This ensures that a certain set of CMake features is available to
# your build.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Specifies a library name, specifies whether the library is STATIC or
# SHARED, and provides relative paths to the source code. You can
# define multiple libraries by adding multiple add.library() commands,
# and CMake builds them for you. When you build your app, Gradle
# automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
             transit-searchengine

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/jni/android_osutils.cpp
             src/main/jni/graph.cpp
             src/main/jni/journey.cpp
             src/main/jni/newsearchengine.cpp
             src/main/jni/searchengine.cpp
             src/main/jni/jniwrapper.cpp )

# Specifies a path to native header files.
include_directories(src/main/jni/)

find_library( # Defines the name of the path variable that stores the
              # location of the NDK library.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # CMake needs to locate.
              log )

# Links your native library against one or more other native libraries.
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       transit-searchengine

                       # Links the log library to the target library.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.versionAndroidSdk
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.versionBuildTools

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.versionMinAndroidSdk
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.versionAndroidSdk
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                // Passes optional arguments to CMake.
                arguments "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang", "-DANDROID_STL=stlport_static", "-DANDROID_UNIFIED_HEADERS=ON"
                cppFlags "-std=c++11"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ndk {
                debuggable true
            }
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ndk {
                debuggable true
            }
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path 'CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After I've looked through the logs before the crash I noticed an error from pthread_create. It seems I was creating too many threads and I need to find another way to manage the thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the source location mentioned in the crash, for your version of the NDK (r14): [new.cc](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/ndk-r14-release/sources/cxx-stl/gabi++/src/new.cc#105).

By the looks of things, `new` tried `malloc`, which failed, returning a `nullptr`, then it tried to get the current [`new_handler`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/new_handler), which failed, because one hasn't been set, so it was forced to explode.

It seems as though you've simply exhausted the memory on your 32bit Android device. If you're running a version of Android below 4.4, then your app may not be allowed to allocate more virtual memory than there is physical memory (Android < 4.4 doesn't utilise any kind of swap memory).

- After 4.4 they added [zRAM](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/low-ram.html#zram) (page compression), which might help: dirty pages can be compressed to take up less RAM. If you can, try running on a 32bit device running 4.4+.
- Or, on a 32bit device with more physical memory.

Comment: After I've looked through the logs before the crash I noticed an error from pthread_create. It seems I was creating too many threads and I need to find another way to manage the thread pool.